# what the author want to say?

Tags: meaning

I was reading a book, but when I reached this statement, I could not continue to do that because I did not understand it. Please tell me what the author want to say in this statement:

For a short while, his death infused otherwise banal and empty experiences with import and meaning.

Comment: What book? What is the context of that statement? To put it bluntly, we can only guess.

Answer (score -1):

The quote is from an essay by Mark Manson, entitled The Uncomfortable Truth. (It always helps to give the source of a quote when you ask a question.)

Among other things the essay describes the impact that the death of a person can have on friends and family. In this case, the death is of the writer's grandfather while the writer was in college and he is describing the impact that the death had on him.

The writer explains that he felt that **it was important for me to carry on hope and aspiration in his honor.**

He felt the need to live with a positive outlook that would have made the old man proud.

That's the background to the quote.

The quote itself is saying that for a short time after his grandfather's death, the writer found that dull day to day events (banal and empty experiences) became deeply meaningful (they were infused with import and meaning) as he concentrated on living in this positive way in memory of the old man.

The idea has echoes of the spirituality of Christian religious orders whose members try to carry out each daily task in God's honour in order to infuse it with meaning.

https://markmanson.net/the-uncomfortable-truth

Comment: Thank you for answering in the fullest possible way

Comment: Love to know why Anonymous down-voted the answer.